# IPython - set a breakpoint in imported file

Tags: python, breakpoints, ipython, pdb

One can set a breakpoint in `IPython` + `pdb` like this:

```
run -d -b 150 file1.py
```

That would break the execution of `file1.py` at line 150.
Now, how can one set  a break point in a file that is being called by `file1.py`? Something like the following:

```
run -d -b file2.py:106 file1.py
```

where `file2.py` is imported and called inside `file1.py`.

Many thanks.

Comment: It looks like this was just merged: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2782

Comment: thanks a lot for the merge (@Owen) and for the link!

Answer (score 5):

One option which you might find workable would be to make `file1.py` into an IPython script, that is, change the name to `file1.ipy`, and then, instead of

```
import file2
```

do

```
%run -d -b 106 file2.py
```

I realize this might not be ideal as it requires editing `file1.py`.

**edit**: This would indeed be a useful feature in the `%run` command. I have added it here: https://github.com/ellbur/ipython

Also if you have a solution using `pdb` you might want to post that as an answer as well.

Comment: I see, that's one possibility I didn't know. As you say it's not ideal but it's a good start. It seems that pdb lets you specify the file as well.